# Solve a recurrence using binary search

Tags: recurrence-relations

For this following recurrence:

$$f(0) = 1,\\
f(1) = 1,\\
f(2) = 2,\\
f(2t) = f(t) + f(t + 1) + t\text{ (for }t > 1),\\
f(2t + 1) = f(t - 1) + f(t) + 1\text{ (for }t \ge 1).$$

After thorough research i know that this should be solved using a binary search one on the even indices and one for the odd.

However i have no idea on how to start with this. I do know what binary search is but have only used them to search for an element in an array.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Also a code sample or pseudo code would be very helpful.

Regards,
Omar

Edit:

To be more specific, I need a solution to be able to find the value t that produces the input x;

check this question for exactly what i need. the solution is there but did not really get it and would appreciate further elaboration.

[convoluted recurrence: $f(2n)=f(n)+f(n+1)+n, f(2n+1)=f(n)+f(n-1)+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045477/convoluted-recurrence-f2n-fnfn1n-f2n1-fnfn-11)

Comment: So... what's the question?  Are we trying to solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: @Winther question edited

Answer (score 0):

In the comment of the indicated answer there is a bounded interval in where to search recursively:

> For n sufficiently large it should be the case that
>   .39nlogn≤f(n)≤.5nlogn. This means if you are
>   trying to solve f(n)=S then, for each S, there is only a finite
>   range (depending on S) that needs to be searched. This gives an
>   algorithm (once you prove the inequalities) for all n sufficiently
>   large; smaller n can be searched through brute force.